# Describing minor triads as 1, b3, 5: convoluted, misleading, or am I missing something?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, terminology, learning

I've found myriad sources describing “Minor Triads” as “1, b3, 5” with emphasis on the ***b3***.    Following an embarrassing amount of head scratching and research, the implication seems to be that ***b3*** in this context, is in reference to the 3rd of our minor chord being one half-step or one semitone lower than the 3rd of the “Major Triad” that would be formed over the same root – a  seemingly trivial nod to the fact that the 3rd interval of the minor scale is the equivalent of the flattened 3rd of the major scale on the same root.  Otherwise, for an Am Triad to be accurately described as “1, ***b3***, 5” it would be have to be spelled  A-***Cb***-E,  instead of simply A–C–E.

Am I wrong in thinking ***1, b3, 5*** is at best a flawed/convoluted, if not downright misleading way of describing “Minor Triads” in general?  Would it not be more concise to describe a Minor-Triad  1,-3, 5 or  R + -3 + Δ3?

Comment: Your beef with the **b3** spelling is a known thing in Chord spelling, which lead to an alternative spelling of the raising/lowering symbols #/b as +/-. So an A minor chord would be spelled as 1,3-,5 (at least in an A major context, in an A minor context A it would be spelled 1,3,5 and A major would be 1,3+,5. Or not. This can be a bit ambivalent ...)

Comment: You were extremely quick to accept an answer, without giving the rest of the world time to wake up!!

Comment: If "b3" causes problems, there will be a lot more ahead. Everyone practices and looks at music in their own way, and talks about it in their own way. There is no central design committee or bureau of musical practices you could file a complaint at.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - that's true enough, which is why we have 'music theory'. But isn't it a darn sight easier to converse with others who use the same terminology/language?

Comment: @Tim Music theories - and there are many of them - are ways of talking about musical practices. Just as there are many different practices, there are many different ways to talk about them. No central music theory committee who defines things.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - more's the pity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you have an accepted answer I would like to add a few points. It is true that in functional harmony chords are generally constructed from different types of major and minor scales. Chords however are entities that very often are independent of keys or scales or functional harmony. For that reason we should think of chord construction using intervals, not scales.

You have m2,M2,m3,M3,P4,+4/o5,P5,m6,M6,m7,M7, then the octave. Beyond that just add 7, 2nds become 9ths, etc.

There is terminology used with chords where the major intervals are referred to as natural, the minor intervals are referred to as flat and the occasional augmented intervals are sharp. These are used for fundamental chord tones (b3,b5) and for upper tensions (b9,9,#9,11,#11,b13,13).

As for calling a minor triad “1,-3, 5”, I have seen + and - used as an alternate to # and b but it is not as common. As for “R + -3 + Δ3”, a triangle is generally used to indicate maj7 but even using just a 3 is not done because chord tones are identified by the relationship to the root, not the individual notes to each other. However it is good to know and be aware of these relationships in general as a musician.

Comment: Isn't this consistent with a major-scale orientation? b9 = lowered 9 compared to major; #9 = raised 9 compared to major; etc.: 9, 11, and 13 all being "native" to the major scale.

Comment: @Aaron Yes it is, “M” and “P” interval names coincide with the degrees of the major scale. What is your point though?

Comment: "m2,M2,m3,M3,P4,+4/o5,P5,m6,M6,m7,M7,..." 
I think I like it!  Could you point to examples of this in context?

Comment: I'm thinking it would have to be something like R+M3+m3 to describe a Major Triad, and R+m3+M3 to describe a minor triad, because  P5 all by itself would be ambiguous?

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Just wasn't clear if your post was intended to contradict or reinforce the idea of the major scale as the reference point.

Comment: @Aaron Neither really, I was just stating intervals are the best reference point for identifying and describing any chord. It just so happens that the measurements for intervals are derivative of the major scale. Chords exist in and outside of keys so it is better to use what I like to think of as the tape measure of music, intervals, to define them instead of scales and keys.

Comment: @TjMcDonald I’ll tackle your second comment first. Standard triads are R,M3,P5 (or R,3,5), for major, R,m3,P5 (or R,b3,5) for minor, R,m3,o5 (or R,b3,b5) for diminished. You can continue and do augmented, sus2, sus4 using the same principles. Your description using the intervals between chord tones is accurate and like I said is very useful to know but is not typically used in describing chords.

Comment: @TjMcDonald Regarding your first comment, here are a few examples using some random chords: Cmaj7: R,M3,P5,M7(or R,3,5,7); F7b9: R,M3,P5,m7,m9 (or R,3,5,b7,b9); Dm6: R,m3,P5,M6 (or R,b3,5,6); Ao7: R,m3,o5,o7 (or R,b3,b5,bb7 with the option of R,b3,o5,o7); This is completely independent of keys and harmonic function and is very accurate. You can see that using the method in parentheses is as accurate and is a sort of shorthand so to speak.

Comment: @TjMcDonald Now I know that say, an F7b9 is M3,m3,m3,m3 but that information is more useful from a practicing or playing perspective than an analytical one.

Comment: It should be noted that chord symbols don't actually just use the major intervals, they use the dominant (seventh) intervals. you specifically didn't talk about the seventh interval, which conventionally is a minor seventh, unless you specify major. I found this unintuitive when learning chord symbols, but it's a quirk from classical music when extensions were mainly used on the dominant chord.

Comment: @KieranJackCommanda This specific question was about triads so I did not address the m7/M7 intervals specifically in my answer although I did mention all 12 intervals in an octave. By the way, it’s not accurate to refer to it/them as the dominant interval(s) because a m7 can also be used on non-dominant chords, like minor 7th chords for example. I did however offer some examples of chords with extensions at the request of the OP in the 2 comments before yours. You are certainly right in that the dominant 7th chord was the most widely used 7th chord in earlier classical music.

Answer (score 3):

Your interpretation is correct in that the comparison is to the major scale, which is the standard reference point.

What makes it confusing is that we usually think of "flat" as being part of the name of the note. In this context, though, it means "lowered by a half step".

Thus, `A minor`, rather than being `A - Cb - E` is `1 - 3-from-major-lowered-by-a-half-step - 5.`

Comment: I feel like this answer omits mention of context. The b3 concept and treating the major scale as default is not universal. It seems to be ubiquitous in jazz centered discussions and much rarer in discussions of 17th to 19th century European art music. Also I would think of it as “a half step lower than the major third” as opposed to “lowered by a half step”. Personally I view scales not as made from alterations from the major scale but as sets of intervals from the tonic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Can you give an example? When I've studied CPE art music, minor was generally described in reference to major (e.g., "the minor scale contains lowered 3rd, 6th, and 7th degrees"). I can easily change "the standard reference point" to "a standard reference point, especially in jazz and pop," but I need some convincing, because in my experience, "minor in terms of major" also applies to CPE music.

Comment: This might be a reflection of my age. I don’t have my theory books from the 90s anymore. [Open music theory](https://viva.pressbooks.pub/openmusictheory/chapter/minor-scales/) starts minor scales by saying they always have a third degree a half step lower than major, but that is quickly followed by the pattern of whole and half steps for the three scale types, which is how I was taught. I feel like the “jazz view” has become more popular outside of jazz over the years.

Comment: I also feel like saying the third degree is a half step lower in the minor scale than it is in the major scale is different from using the flat symbol in “b3”. That’s because as this asker has implied, the b symbol in “b3” can seem to suggest there would be an actual flat accidental in the notation of the scale/key. The linked open music theory page does not use “b3”, “b6” or “b7” in its description of the minor scale

Comment: This example builds minor scales exclusively using intervals from the tonic with no foundation in the major scale: https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/22

Comment: In my quest for concision, eschewing ambiguity, I can't escape the sense of an underlying mathematical precision here, in search of a simple vernacular to describe it... Would I be correct asserting that Minor Triads -- ALL OF THEM can be accurately described/thought of as "R, iii, V"  ???

Comment: @TjMcDonald Yes. However, if you use that notation in describing chords to another musician, you could run into trouble. Roman numerals are commonly reserved for chords rather than notes within chords.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'd chalk it up to teaching style. I was taught the "major is normative" way, but I prefer the "half-steps and whole-steps" way.

Comment: @TjMcDonald - ^1 ^(b)3 ^5 would be better, as RN is used for *chords*, whereas ^1 etc is used for particular individual notes. Maybe with a little 3...

Comment: Flattened/ a semitone lower, what the heck?

Comment: @Tim Don't understand your question.

Comment: Just joining the conversation - flattened and a semitone (or even half-step) lower are surely the same things? Or are there semantics involved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140591/discussion-between-aaron-and-tim).

Answer (score 1):

We name intervals in relation to the major scale starting on the lower note of the interval.  If we want a minor 3rd above C♯, we look at the scale of C♯ major.   The third note is E♯, so C♯ to E♯ would be a major 3rd.  To get a minor 3rd we must flatten the E♯ by a half-step, giving E♮.

Yes, there is room for confusion when 'flattening' a note results in something that doesn't have a flat in its name. Maybe it would be better if we didn't use the term 'flatten', rather 'lower'.   But 'flatten' IS in general use, and there's not much you can do about it!

Answer (score 0):

The major scale notes, like it or not, are now decidedly the datum points. There does need to be a start point, and that's where it is. Trouble is, the whole thing is muddied by what does major and minor mean?

Major *could* mean largest, minor smallest, or major most important, minor less so.

With scale notes, it would be silly to assume the first, so the second definition comes into play. Whereas with intervals (that's what's at stake here) the wider ones are called major, compared with the narrower ones, minor.

So, Using the major scale notes as our datum point, m3 is smaller (narrower) than M3. By the smallest margin generally in use, one semitone. So saying the minor triad differs from the major triad because its 3rd is ♭3 is acceptable. Surely it's the same as saying it's a flat third? That only means it's actually a flat third when that note, in a major key, is a natural which then becomes a flat, and if that note is already a sharpened note, due to key signature, it becomes a natural of the same name - C♯ becomes C♮ when changing A major into A minor.

That's, I think, where your reasoning is flawed. Using major triad A C♯ E, with a M3 as the defining factor, flattening that C♯ will **not** make it C♭. How could it? Flattening a sharpened note merely makes it a natural. What you did was *double flatten* it. There's absolutely no reason for that. Changing A>C♯ (major 3) into A>C ♮ (minor 3) is exactly what happens, which results in A C E - Am triad!

We've taken a larger interval and reduced it by one semitone (as discussed earlier) to make it smaller, M3>m3. Somehow, you made that interval (by retaining the name 'C') into a *diminished* interval, which has no place in either major or minor triads.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of your confusion is between theory (a minor triad has a flattened 3rd with respect to the default), and the most common notation (you'd very rarely see it written "♭3" or "-3", because normally, this more readable using "m", as in "Am").

To summarise:

**A**   =  A major,  A,C# E

**Am**  =  A minor (third),  A,C,E

**A7**  =  A major with a 7th (A,C#,E,G) - note that "the" 7th is, by convention, not the 7th note of the A-major scale but the minor-7th, because it is more common.

**AM7** =  A major with an explicitly Major 7th  (A,C#,E,G#)

**AmM7** =  A minor with a Major 7th  (A,C,E,G#)

You also see some weirder things:

**Adim**   =  A diminished (A,C,E♭)  i.e. flattened 3rd and 5th.

**AM3♭5**    = A major with a flattened 5th, i.e. (A,C#,E♭). This is rather unusual because it sounds so odd. The "M3" is required, because it has to be distinguished from: **A♭5** .

**A♭5**     = a power chord in A♭, containing just A♭, E♭.
It is *not* A with a flattened 5th, i.e. (A,C#, E♭).

(i.e. if the 2nd character is a ♭ or #, it binds to the character before it, even though all subsequent ♭ or # bind to the character after them).  However **Am♭5** is the same as Adim.

HTH.

Comment: In the case of A7, the chord actually belongs to key D, which is where G natural resides. Although used a lot in key A, that's not where it's from. Also, Adim is better described as R, m3, d5. (Since all the other descriptions you use refer to maj/min).